# How to make Firefox open JAR files with the registered default program

Tags: windows, firefox, java, file-association, content-type-association

When downloading a `*.jar` file, Firefox doesn't ask me if I want to open or download the file. It only offers the option to download it. Is there any way to configure Firefox to ask, like for most other file extensions?

It seems that Firefox considers JAR files to be executables, and therefore disables the "open" option. This may be true on many systems (where `*.jar` files are executed with Java) but not for me. I have JAR files opened with WinRAR by default. So how can I tell Firefox that it is safe to open JAR files?